# Gradient numbers for multiple svg export from illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, export, gradient

When exporting to svg from Illustrator, the code generates a "linear-gradient-" or "radial-gradient-" plus number. This seems to work until I export multiple files with different gradients. No matter how I name them in the Graphic Styles, Illustrator exports them and names the gradients chronological, restarting for each file. This means that when used on a website the gradients completely mess up because multiple are called the same e.g. "linear-gradient-2". Is there a way to export the svg's so that this naming convention isn't used? or do I have to fix the code manually?

**Ex1**

```
<linearGradient id="linear-gradient-2" x1="662.49" y1="137.19" x2="796.91" y2="271.61" gradientTransform="matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 578)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ff7900"/>
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#ffa300"/>
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#f59c00"/>
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#ce8201"/>
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#b67102"/>
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#ad6b02"/>
</linearGradient>
```

**Ex2**

```
<linearGradient id="linear-gradient-2" x1="234.52" y1="892.3" x2="234.52" y2="1254" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#2d4847"/>
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#294c4c"/>
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#1c595b"/>
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#066f73"/>
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#00757a"/>
</linearGradient>
```

Comment: You *could* edit the XML of the exported svgs to give each gradient a unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

No solution for the gradients, even making them on the same file and different artboard.

But following [this answer](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1335983):

[image: adobe forum]

Instead of making a gradient, try with **blending**, here is a [Codepen sample](https://codepen.io/danielillo/pen/xjozZO).

[image]